# SSRS Report Builder 3.0 Sum multiple Scopes in denominator

Tags: reporting-services, scope, sum, ssrs-grouping

I have a scope issue in the summing of values to get a percentage.

What I have:

`=Fields!UPC_COUNT.Value/Sum(Fields!UPC_COUNT.Value, "C2")`

What I need is something like this:

`=Fields!UPC_COUNT.Value/Sum(Fields!UPC_COUNT.Value, "C2" & "AREA")`

Any Ideas?

Image Describing the dilemma

[image: Valid XHTML]

Comment: If I try to do what I need, I get : "The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox67.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset."

Comment: Provide a sample dataset in order to help you.

Comment: Can't you use `=Fields!UPC_COUNT.Value/(Sum(Fields!UPC_COUNT.Value, "C2") + Sum(Fields!UPC_COUNT.Value, "AREA") ) `?

Comment: Adding them together will give me all UPC's. I need where the two intersect. In case SSRS did something in the background, I tried it and it confirmed that it added all UPCs in C2 and All UPCs in AREA within the dataset. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: Alejandro, I do not know how to provide a sample dataset. Can you point me to an example? From that, I will add a sample dataset of my own. Thank you

Comment: @EPWebS25, Edit your question to include a table containing the data returned by your dataset. Format it as is explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96125/how-to-format-sql-tables-in-a-stack-overflow-post) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)